# Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on boolean

Tags: php

Выполняю задачу по роутерам. В процессе выполнения возникла ошибка:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on boolean + место ошибки.

Место, куда ссылается ошибка:

> $this->router->add('home', '/', 'HomeController:index');

Код класса:

```
 public function __construct($di)
{
  $this->di = $di;
  $this->router = $this->di->get('router');
}

public function run()
{
     $this->router->add('home', '/', 'HomeController:index');
     print_r($this->di);
}
```

Сама функция `add`:

```
public function add($key, $pattern, $controller, $method = 'GET')
{
    $this->routes[$key] = [
        'pattern' => $pattern,
        'controller' => $controller,
        'method' => $method
    ];

}
```

Comment: Видимо нет ключа `'router'` у вас в `routes`

Comment: В констракторе и становится булевого типа. Тут: `$this->di->get('router');` Видно `get()` возвращает `false` какой-нибудь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В месте вызова `$this->router->add('home', '/', 'HomeController:index');`
переменная `$this->router` - булевого типа. Попытайтесь найти, где она раньше переходит в этот тип. Возможно Вы не определили роутер в вашем DI контейнере.

Comment: В констракторе и становится булевого типа. Тут: `$this->di->get('router');` Видно `get` возвращает `false` какой-нибудь.

Comment: В булев тип перейти вряд ли должен. Так как в провайдере указано:     
  $router = new Router('http://router.loc/');

Comment: @ОлегКавалевский зачем отрицать очевидное? Черным по белому ведь написано, метод вызывается у булевой переменной.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону контейнера, почему он возвращает `false`